# Delete a record using laravel delete function

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I want to delete a record from my table named post. I am sending a param named tag in my view to delete a certain record against this tag.
 So here is my route

```
   Route::get('/delete' , array('as' =>'delete' , 'uses' => 'Postcontroller@deletepost'));
```

by this route i am delete my post against it's 'tag' field. my table has two column. one is tag and other is content 
My delete fucntion in PostController is

```
   public function deletepost($tag){

   $post = post::find($tag); //this is line 28 in my fuction
   $post->delete();
   echo ('record is deleted') ;
   }
```

I am send tag from my view but it is giving the following error

```
  ErrorException in Postcontroller.php line 28:
  Missing argument 1 for
  App\Http\Controllers\Postcontroller::deletepost()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action should look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function deletepost(Request $request) // add Request to get the post data
{
    $tagId = $request->input('id'); // here you define $tagId by the post data you send
    $post = post::find($tagId);
    if ($post) {
        $post->delete();
        echo ('record is deleted!');
    } else {
        echo 'record not found!');
    }
}
```

Comment: public function deletepost(Request $request)
              {
             $tagId = $request->input('tag');
              $post = post::find($tagId);
             $post->delete($tagId );
            echo ('record is deleted') ;
             }
by changing this followinf error came
Call to a member function delete() on null

Comment: And change `$tagId = $request->input('id');`, the `id` to the name of the post id identifier sent by the post request.

Comment: i think in 5.3 we have to use get method instead of input. but your logic worked. Thanks 
and if we want to delete any record on the custom bases , other than primary key we have to specify our condition.

Comment: Actually I was playing around with Laravel since 5.4, but I'm glad you've found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the parameter for an example if you pass it like tag_id then you have to capture it inside the controller function using Request.

```
public function deletepost(Request $request){

   $post = post::find($request::get('tag_id')); 
   $post->delete();
   echo ('record is deleted');
}
```

Comment: Your Welcome :D Qadeer_Sipra

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the route to expect that parameter.
You should try it this way in your routes file:

```
Route::get('/delete/{tag}' , array('as' =>'delete' , 'uses' => 'Postcontroller@deletepost'));
```

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:  now browser is show this error